# Command that works in terminal does not work using System

Tags: c, smtp, command, system, sendmail

I can use this command for sending an email, and it works

```
echo -e "To:pedromiguel-99@hotmail.com\nSubject:OLA\n\nPQP" | sendmail -t
```

However, using this line of code in C

```
system("echo -e \"To:pedromiguel-99@hotmail.com\nSubject:Test\n\nTest\" | sendmail -t");
```

it says

> sendmail: No recipients specified although -t option used

Why does the terminal and the function not produce the same result?

Comment: your terminal might be `bash` and your system *shell* (invoked by `system`) might be `sh` accounting for the difference in behavior for the `echo` command

Comment: Oh. That makes sense... How coudl I work around that?

Comment: Instead of using `system` and `echo ... | sendmail -t`, look at `popen`. (e.g.) `FILE *fp = popen("sendmail -t","w"); fputs("To:pedromiguel-99...",fp); ...; pclose(fp);`

Comment: I will try that, thank you